# Using htmlAgilityPack scraping all inner text from <a> tag

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack, web-scraping

I want to scrap all the word  from the link http://search.freefind.com/siteindex.html?id=59478474&ltr=10240&fwr=0&pid=i&ics=1
I tried something like this:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://search.freefind.com/siteindex.html?id=59478474&ltr=10240&fwr=0&pid=i&ics=1");
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@class='search-index-font']//a");

if (nodes != null)
{

    foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
    {
         link = n.InnerText;
        my_link.Add(link);
        MessageBox.Show(link);
    }

}
else
    MessageBox.Show("no wordfound ");
```

My expexted output should like

```
a    
aa
aachhe
aagrashi
aagun
aaj
aam
aanka
aankhi
aar
aashman
abāddhō
abāddhōtā
abadh
..
..
```

But it didn't work??**It shows "no word found"** Means it returns null.How can i get all text from   < a > tag in that case???
 ***Can anyone tell me What should be in SelectNodes("")???***

Comment: What _did_ happen? "it didn't work" is not a great description that helps with solving the problem.

Comment: It shows "no word found"....

Comment: The markup on that page is completely broken. There are no opening `a` elements in the block you are searching at at all. For instance: `</script>a</a><br><script>findindexitem('aa');</script>aa</a>` - There is no `<a>` for the HAP to match on.

Comment: It looks like this `findindexitem` script adds the opening tag - meaning you need to get the source _after_ JavaScript executed on the page.

Comment: How can i fix that?What should be my SelectNodes("")??@Oded

Comment: You can't - it is invalid HTML. You will need to use something else.

Comment: what should ?? can you tell me what should i do for this??i also used SelectNodes("a[@class='search-index-links']") but it also gives the same result.  @Oded

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. Did you understand that the HTML is not valid when loading the page, unless JavaScript runs? The HTML Agility Pack can't execute JavaScript. So either get the HTML after JavaScript runs and copy it locally - then run the HAP against it, or use some other method.

Comment: seems relavent http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29175

Comment: That page is oldschool, it uses document.write to build itself, for no particularly useful reason. It would be pretty easy to recode this on the server in your scraper if this is a one-off.

Comment: perhaps the real question is, why do you need to scrape this page? It doesn't seem like volatile content to me. Don't you just want to get a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search for the next text node after `<script>` tag(not `<a>` tag as you said), inside `<font class='search-index-font'>`. This xpath expression will do the trick:

```
//font[@class='search-index-font']/script/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

And this code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://search.freefind.com/siteindex.html?id=59478474&ltr=10240&fwr=0&pid=i&ics=1");
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@class='search-index-font']/script/following-sibling::text()[1]");
```

will return text nodes you need:

```
a
aa
aachhe
aagrashi
aagun
aaj
aam
aanka
aankhi
aar
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@class='search-index-font']//a");
```

returns `null`, as documented [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29175).

That is because there are no `a` elements in `font` elements with a `class` attribute equal to `search-index-font` in the html you have loaded in `doc`.

---

If you change the xpath you pass to `SelectNodes` to select something that exists then your code will take a different path. Without knowing what you to achieve I can't advise further.

---

You can use HAP to parse the valid html, i.e. use it to identify the script elements. Then you'll have to hand roll something to parse the inner text of the script tag to extract what you want.

Ultimately, what you want is a list of Bengali words.

Comment: I got that?? But in that case how can i solve this and get my desired result??Do u have any solve??@Jodrell

Comment: @user2029069, what is it you actually want to do?

Comment: That's pretty weird, it's using JS to generate the opening <a> tags. So you'll have to replace the <script>findindexitem('aa');</script> with an open <a> tag before it's even valid XHTML.

Comment: @Jodrell. Actually i want all the words from that page.I hv given a demo output in my question.Please see that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='search-index-links']");
```

instead of

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@class='search-index-font']//a");
```

Comment: It gives same result."no words found"

Comment: I have tried many times but it gives no result to me and then i post it here.

Comment: Try using Selenium instead of HTML Agility Pack. Selenium will execute the script and then you will be able to get the data

[Selenium web driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc =
    web.Load("http://search.freefind.com/siteindex.html?id=59478474&ltr=10240&fwr=0&pid=i&ics=1");
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@class='search-index-font']");
string link = string.Empty;
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (var item in nodes)
    {
        var value =
        item.Elements("script").ToList();
        foreach (var items in value)
        {
            link += items.NextSibling.InnerText+ "\n";
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(link);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("no wordfound ");
```

Comment: Could you please explain "var value=item.Elements("script").ToList();" this line??@John

Comment: Cause in font tag are many elements, I am selecting only script tags,if you will debug code, you will saw in watch.